# JSON deserialized object returns null

Tags: c#, json, uwp, json.net, uwp-xaml

#### Source Code - Main class

```
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        status.result deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<status.result>(responseBody);

        Debug.WriteLine(deserializeObject.SafeGasPrice.ToString());
```

#### Source Code - JSON Class

```
    public class status
    {
        public class result
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SafeGasPrice")]
            public int SafeGasPrice { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProposeGasPrice")]
            public int ProposeGasPrice { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FastGasPrice")]
            public int FastGasPrice { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

#### Output

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":{"LastBlock":"14296250","SafeGasPrice":"96","ProposeGasPrice":"96","FastGasPrice":"97","suggestBaseFee":"95.407119606","gasUsedRatio":"0.174721033333333,0.523179548504219,0.056945596868572,0.999939743363228,0.953861217484817"}}

0
```

#### Problem

I don't currently understand why a null is output, my guess is that I have implemented the json deserialization classes incorrectly.

Comment: You're missing a class corresponding to the outer `{"result": { }}` object.

Comment: How do I implement this as code?

Comment: @amazingh Is this what you are looking for: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hm6HNL ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, @dbc has already posted a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model does not correspond to the JSON provided, it is missing a type corresponding to the outer `{"result": { }}` object:

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "message":"OK",
   "result":{
      // This inner object corresponds to your model.
      "LastBlock":"14296250",
      "SafeGasPrice":"96",
      "ProposeGasPrice":"96",
      "FastGasPrice":"97",
      "suggestBaseFee":"95.407119606",
      "gasUsedRatio":"0.174721033333333,0.523179548504219,0.056945596868572,0.999939743363228,0.953861217484817"
   }
}
```

To work around the problem, you need to introduce an outer, wrapper model.  You could make an explicit one like so:

```
public class Root
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SafeGasPrice")]
    public int SafeGasPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProposeGasPrice")]
    public int ProposeGasPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FastGasPrice")]
    public int FastGasPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize like so:

```
var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseBody)?.result;
```

Or, you could use an [anonymous type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) for the root model like so:

```
var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(responseBody, new { result = default(Result) })?.result;
```

Either way you will now be able to successfully deserialize the inner, nested properties.

So what did you do wrong? In your question, you declare `result` as a [**nested type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types):

```
public class status
{
    public class result
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SafeGasPrice")]
        public int SafeGasPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProposeGasPrice")]
        public int ProposeGasPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FastGasPrice")]
        public int FastGasPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All this does is define a type `result` within the scope of another type `status`.  It does not create a **property** named `result` within `status`.  As there is no need for such nesting I recommend moving `result` out from inside `status` and renaming it `Result` to follow standard .NET naming conventions.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/csnZXQ).

Comment: So when I define JSON properties I need to define every name field, is that correct?

The way you did it with Root, I didn't know I needed to define other non-essential name fields as well.

Comment: @amazingh - you don't need to define every property name, you only need do define property names for the fields you need to deserialize. I generated the `Root` model using https://json2csharp.com/ which adds them in automatically, but you may omit `status` and `message` if you don't want them.

Comment: That is astonishing. I didn't know there was such a converter. Thank you for your time.